# Why can't i get sendgrid to replace my variables in my template when using their smtpapi?

Tags: ruby, sendgrid

I believe that i have followed the documentation on SendGrid's site but so far when I receive an email that I've sent through their API it never substitutes the replacements i've specified in the x-smtpapi headers. I am using HTTParty to send the request like this:

```
HTTParty.post(Sendgrid::Postman.api_url, { 
    :query => params.merge({ "api_user" => @config[:api_user], "api_key" => @config[:api_key] }), 
    :headers => headers, :format => :json
  })
```

the "params" look like this:

```
{"from"=>"noreply@foo.com", "text"=>"Happy Holidays -first_name- -last_name-,\nI hope this message finds you in good health and high spirits.", "to"=>["foo@gmail.com"], "subject"=>"foo"}
```

The Headers look like this:

```
{"X-SMTPAPI"=>"{\"sub\": {\"-first_name-\": [\"Foo\"], \"-email-\": [\"foo@gmail.com\"], \"-login-\": [\"heavysixer\"], \"-last_name-\": [\"Bar\"]}, \"to\": [\"foo@gmail.com\"]}"}
```

The mail is always successfully delivered but when it arrives in the inbox the values that were supposed to be substituted still appear like -first_name- & -last_name-

What am I missing? I've been messing around with this for a solid day now?

### -----------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE:
Per the advice below I have tried to push the x-smtpapi params into the form post yet I am getting the same result. The query string for my post now looks like this:

```
params = {"api_user" => 'foo', "api_key" => 'bar', "from"=>"noreply@foo.com", "text"=>"Happy Holidays -first_name- -last_name-,\nI hope this message finds you in good health and high spirits.", "to"=>["foo@gmail.com"], "subject"=>"foo", "x-smtpapi"=>{"sub"=>{"-first_name-"=>["foo"], "-email-"=>["foo@gmail.com"], "-login-"=>["foo"], "-last_name-"=>["bar"]}}}

HTTParty.post(Sendgrid::Postman.api_url, :query => params, :format => :json)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their [documentation](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/web-api/mail/) implies that x-smtpapi should be one of the posted parameters, not an http header.

Comment: If you look at this document it looks like it's specifying a header: http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/smtp-api/ruby-example/

Comment: That's for their SMTP api. If you look at the actual examples for the web api, it's a parameter (the examples are in php but it's pretty obvious what is going on)

Comment: I see what you are saying. I have relocated the "x-smtpapi" into the query param but it still does not replace the values. I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: As it turns out i needed to replace some of the generated json to get it to properly work. However you were correct it does go as a param in the post and not in the header. Thanks so much for your help! {'x-smtpapi' => { 'to' => @params['to'], 'sub' => @params['sub'] }.to_json.gsub(/(["\]}])([,:])(["\[{])/, '\\1\\2 \\3')